# looping through array in cakephp still has Undefined offset

Tags: php, arrays, loops, cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.2.5 for this.

I've got a contained find in one controller that pulls a list of four news items from a 'has many' relationship.

I'm trying to produce a list of these four items, but can't seem to get the php foreach loop working.

the controller array is this:

```
    $newsLists = $this->Industry->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('id' => $id),
        'fields' => array('id'),
        'contain' => array(     
            'News' => array(
                'conditions' => array('News.type' => 'main','News.active' => 'Yes'),                        
                    'fields' => array(
                            'News.type', 
                            'News.id',
                            ),
                    'order' => array(
                        'News.created' => 'desc',
                       ),
                    'limit' => 3
        ))));


    $this->set('newsLists', $newsLists);
```

The debug output works fine:

```
  Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Industry] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [tags] => 
            )

        [News] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => main
                        [id] => 10
                        [industry_id] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => main
                        [id] => 11
                        [industry_id] => 1
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => main
                        [id] => 12
                        [industry_id] => 1
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

but this foreach loop only display one item:

```
<ul>
<?php 
$i = 0;

foreach ($newsLists as $newsList): ?>

        <li><?php echo $newsList['News'][$i]['slug']; ?></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution involves creating another loop since there is a has many relationship between industry and news. This extra loop allows the news stories to be looped through.

```
<?php foreach ($newsLists as $newsList): ?>
 <ul>
    <?php foreach ($newsList ['News'] as $list): ?>
    <li><?php echo $list['slug']; ?></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be -

```
<?php foreach ($newsLists['News'] as $newsList): ?>

        <li><?php echo $newsList['field to print']; ?></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Some points you should take care off -

```
There is no slug field.

You have mentioned fields - type & id. But the industry_id is also fetched.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have there two problems:

1. you `echo`es an entry using `$i` but never increment this value, `$i` is still 0. And there is only one-step loop, you loop over the array with only one record.
2. `slug` isn't defied in your array, only one of `type, id, industry_id` can be used

Ad 1.
Correct way is:

```
foreach ($newsLists['News'] as $newsList) {
    echo '<li>' . $newsList['type'] . '</li>'; // you can switch type to id or industry_id
}
```

Comment: thanks for the two tips. I've now made this change but still receive an error: <ul>
 <?php 
 for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) 

 foreach ($newsLists['News'] as $newsList): ?>
  
   <li><?php echo $newsList['News'][$i]['slug']; ?></li>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul> Errors: Notice (8): Undefined index: News, Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). I've also added slug into the field list.

Comment: @Paul: you need no `for` loop there. What I answered is full code, just these three lines. No `$i` is needed.

Comment: thanks @panther. I've added the following, but am still getting the 'Notice (8): Undefined index: News' and 'Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach()', code I changed to: <?php
foreach ($newsLists['News'] as $newsList) {
    echo '<li>' . $newsList['type'] . '</li>'; 
}
?>

Comment: hi @panther, I've resolved this now. I suspected that since this there is a has many relationship between industry and news that I would need another loop. This could works now: <?php foreach ($newsLists as $newsList): ?>
<ul>
  <?php foreach ($newsList ['News'] as $list): ?>
    <li><?php echo $list['slug']; ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>